# PHP Prepared Statement Problems

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

slowly getting used to PHP prepared statements, however still get this error

> "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\login.php on line 20".

```
 <?php

 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'c3337015', 'c3337015', 'members');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

 if(isset($_GET['loginEmail'])){

 session_start();

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Email FROM members WHERE Email=? AND  Password=? LIMIT 1");
    $email = $_GET['loginEmail'];
    $password = $_GET['loginPassword'];
    $password = sha1($password);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            while($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row

              {$_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
               $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
               header('Location: index.php');
               exit();
               }
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else 
    {   
    echo "Something went Wrong";
    }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
```

You are binding 2 variables, but only asking for one: `SELECT Email FROM members`.

I'd also suggest using different variables for `bind_result`, as it and `bind_param` both work on references.

```
$stmt->bind_result($userEmail);
```

Comment: Quick question Rocket. Would it have worked had the query been `SELECT * FROM members` or would it have also potentially fetched too many columns, therefore resulting in a `Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: You can't use `SELECT *` with `bind_result`.  You need to specify the fields.